# Copying 1 single character into string

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to create a ASCII table using a customized Abstract data type

```
typedef struct dictionary {
    int code;
    char* str;
}dictionary;
```

and I encounter an exception when trying to do the following code

```
dictionary table[4096];
void preset() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        char temp = 0 + i;
        table[i].str = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char));
        strcpy(table[i].str,temp);
    }
}
```

I don't understand how I access memory wrongly, can someone help ?

Comment: That should not even compile - at least not without warnings. It is `strcpy(char*, char*)` not `strcpy(char*, char)` Also note that (assuming this is "close")  you'll need to malloc 2 chars. One for the value and one for the 0 terminator

Comment: Pay attention to the prefix of the function name ***str...*** expects to operate on C-strings. A C-string includes the *nul-terminating* character at the end (otherwise it is simply a character array). A minimum you need 2-characters of storage to store a 1-character string. Your alternative is to allocate a single-character and **assign** the character to your `table[i].str` (note using an 8-byte pointer to 1-byte or storage to store 1-bytes is 900% inefficient.

Answer (score 2):

Three problems:

1) You have to allocate an extra byte for the null terminator of the target string:

```
table[i].str = malloc(2);
```

2) You have to pass a pointer to the source to strcpy (this probably caused your segfault):

```
strcpy(table[i].str,&temp);
```

3) The source string has to be null terminated, which it isn't in your code. This is not easy to fix directly. But you do not need strcpy() anyway, just set the two bytes directly:

```
table[i].str[0] = i;
table[i].str[1] = 0;
```

Then it should work as you expect.